# Server disconnects when rendering symfony 1.4 template

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to track down an intermittent problem. On certain actions/pages the user ends up with a server dropped connection error and reloading the page produces the same problem.

I've checked the logs and Symfony goes all the way to sending the content of the page but nothing is actually sent by the server. This only happens on specific pages that happen to be using Zend OAuth.

I've tried increasing the `output_buffering` in php.ini and increasing the `memory_limit` neither of which made a difference.

It only happens where Zend Framework 1.12 components are being used and doesn't happen all the time. If I restart apache the error goes away for a while. There are occasional `zend_mm_heap` error which seems to coincide with the behaviour starting.

The setup is:
Symfony 1.4
Apache 1.2.22
APC 1.3.17
PHP 5.4-precise

I'm stumped and open to suggestions to possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

After much head banging and otherwise general confusion, it seems the bug was related to a combination of PHP5.4, Apache2.2, Zend Framework 1.12 and Symfony 1.4

Due to other circumstances Apache was upgraded to 2.4 and PHP to 5.5. and now the problem is no longer occurring.

Morale of the story is that sometimes the upgrade fixes it.